# Is there a easier way to set order of column when altering table in Laravel migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Let say I already got a table in my MySQL database, and I want to add columns to it. To do so, I am doing it like the following:

```
Schema::table('mytable', function($table) {
    $table->integer('my_special_integer')->after('previous_column');
    $table->text('my_special_text')->after('my_special_integer');
    $table->string('my_special_string')->after('my_special_text');
    /*Some many other field*/
    $table->string('my_last_column_to_add')->after('my_second_last_column');
}
```

Is there a less repeating way if I would simply like to input a bunch of column after a certain previous column?

Answer (score 0):

No, after() just applies the sql AFTER sql statement.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN  new_column
AFTER       existing_column
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do it out of the box, however, what you could do is something like:

```
$columns = [
        'my_special_integer'    => 'integer',
        'my_special_text'       => 'text',
        'my_special_string'     => 'string',
        'my_last_column_to_add' => 'string',
];

$previous = 'previous_column';

foreach ($columns as $name => $type) {
    $table->$type($name)->after($previous);
    $previous = $name;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can use mysql query to alter the column in migration with `DB::statement` like below

```
public function up()
{

DB::statement("ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN column_name1 AFTER column_name2");

}
```